# How can I disable automatic background clearing in a Java graphical application?

Tags: java, netbeans, graphics, background, buffer

I am a Java developer with some expertise in graphical programming but not very skilled with the most recent techniques.

I am developing a Java graphical application using Apache Netbeans IDE 11.2; the application includes many structured panels (split panels, tab controls) and executes 2D drawings on some of them, using Swing and AWT.

The application worked well until now. After the last modifications, I am facing the following problem:

- The application properly performs all drawings (polylines, rectangles and so on) on the main panel, but abruptly the panel is cleared and the original background restored, deleting all drawings.
- The debugging shows that the clearing is not performed by any statement of the program. So I suppose that it is managed behind the scenes by AWT or something like this.
- I understood that Swing automatically implements double buffering (anyway I also inserted a         setDoubleBuffered statement), so I made the drawings directly on the screen without using a buffer. On the other hand, this had worked perfectly until now.

My questions are:

- How can I detect the event that causes the causes the restore of the background? And how can I prevent this restore?
- A solution could be to disable Swing Double Buffering and code it explicitly. I am not sure of this. Any hint?

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Comment: *"How can I detect the event that causes the causes the restore of the background? And how can I prevent this restore?"* Generally speaking, you don't.  Instead, you work with the API in the way it's intended to be used.  This means, overriding `paintComponent` and performing any paint operations within it.  Painting is destructive.  It's intended that when `paintComponent` is called, you would completely repaint the current state of the component.  If what you are painting is complex or time consuming to reproduce, then you should use a backing buffer (ie a `BufferedImage`)

Comment: *"A solution could be to disable Swing Double Buffering and code it explicitly. I am not sure of this. Any hint?"* - Don't

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you start by looking at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how the painting process works and how you are expected to work with it

Comment: Also, remember, Swing is NOT thread safe.  This means you should not be updating the UI directly or indirectly from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: The `Graphics` context used to paint a component is transient.  You should not be using or relying on `getGraphics` nor should you be maintaining a reference to the `Graphics` context which is passed to `paintComponent`.  Instead, when `paintComponent` is called, you work with the passed context only - do not paint out side of these paint cycles, unless you're using your own backing buffer which can be drawn to this context when requested by the system

Comment: As @MadProgrammer well states (in more words), yours is a classic [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) where you ask "how do I do 'X'" when the best solution is not to do 'X' but rather to do 'Y'. Your answer lies in another castle. :D

Comment: Thank you very much, @MadProgrammer! very useful comments and suggestions. Actually, I need some memory refresh about Java graphicaò stuff.